# Display vertical pages for UITextView in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone

How i can display vertical pages for `UITextView` in `UIScrollview`

```
self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 410)]autorelease];

    self.textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-Bold" size:14];

    self.textView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    //self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:2.0/12 saturation:2.0 brightness:4.0/10 alpha:1.0];

    self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.textView.editable = NO;

    self.textView.delegate = self;

    self.textView.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;

    self.textView.layer.borderWidth = 1;

    self.textView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];

    self.textView.layer.cornerRadius = 1;

    self.textView.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;

 self.textView.text = @"Juice fasting makes every other natural method work faster...............";

[self.view addSubview:self.textView]; 

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, textView.frame.size.height);

    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.75;

    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    scrollView.delegate = self;

    scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.textView];

    [button release];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I have a long text in `UITextView`. How i can display this `UITextView` in vertical pages when user scrolls.

Appreciate help.

Comment: if either answer helped you, make sure to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try paging?

```
textView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

Is that what you want? Otherwise I probably would recommend using a default UILabel in a default UIScrollView, to set this up. (Adding one UILabel per page to the scrollView)

Comment: Then go with my second approach. Calculate the needed height for the label using `[label.text sizeWithFont: label.font]`, add the label to the scrollview, set the contentSize approppriate and enable paging on the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Make the text view large enough so that there is no scrolling within it (or change it to a UILabel), and put that inside a separate scrollView.

Then set

> scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

and make sure the height of the content size is larger than the height of the actual scroll view. So if the text view is 320x960, make the scroll view 320x480.

Comment: textview is already a scrollview. He isn't using a seperate scrollview. UITextView seems to prohibit paging.

Comment: Then he should use a separate scrollView. Just make the text view large enough that it doesn't need to scroll by itself. Or switch the TextView into a label and set up the scrollview.